# Retrieve Database name from dataSource

Tags: mysql, grails, datasource

Inside my config.groovy file I define dataSource.url='jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydbname?autoReconnect=true&characterEncoding=utf8'

Is it possible to retrieve 'mydbname' from within a controller? I have injected dataSource, which is giving a 
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy but from there, I cant figure how to get the DB name. The DB name should be retrieved without any String parsing, as the configurations used for the app can change a lot between environments, so ideally I am looking for a method like .getDatasourceName()

I have tried this:
`flash.message = "DB name ${dataSource.getConnection().getClientInfo()}"` but the message returned is this: `DB name [:]`

Comment: You can run a SQL statement to get that: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best you can do is retrieve the URL, then parse out the database name. You can do this like so:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils

class MyController {

  DataSource dataSource

  String getDatabaseName() {
    def url = dataSource.targetDataSource.targetDataSource.poolProperties.url

    url = StringUtils.substringAfterLast(url, '/')
    return StringUtils.substringBefore(url, '?')
  }
}
```

This should return the database name regardless of any datasource URL params, e.g. it will work for all of the following:

- jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydbname?autoReconnect=true&characterEncoding=utf8
- jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydbname?autoReconnect=true
- jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydbname

Comment: I am currently using this: 
  final sqlQuery = sessionFactory.currentSession.createSQLQuery("SELECT DATABASE()")
  params.db_name = sqlQuery.uniqueResult()
But I will also test your answer.

Comment: @Giannis I don't think `SELECT DATABASE()` is portable, but if you're always using MySQL, I guess this doesn't matter

Answer (score 1):

Grooviest way:

```
def dataSource
private String getDatabaseName(){
    def url = dataSource.targetDataSource.targetDataSource.poolProperties.url
    return url.split('/').toList().last().tokenize('?')[0]      
}
```

It works in both ways, with and without url params.